# how to fetch a single value from a reference to another collection?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have two collections - users and chats. Each chat message has a structure like the following:

```
_id: ObjectId
from: ObjectId // user _id
to: ObjectId // user _id
message: String
date_created: Date
```

And each user has:

```
_id: ObjectId
name: String
username: String
// ... not important stuff
```

I need to fetch conversations that are only sent to me and the result should be in the following way:

```
{
    data: [
        {
            "id": conversation_id,
            "title": username,
            "message": message_excerpt
        },...
    ]
}
```

My problem is trying to get the username from the reference because I don't want to make 20 fetch queries to get 20 different usernames. I would have added the username when the conversation is first created but I can't because the username can be changed any time. This would create an inconsistency between the username and the conversation title. How should I handle this problem? This is the first time I wished there was a JOIN in Mongo.

Comment: It seems you have the `_id: ObjectId` doesn't that uniquely identify the user? Not familiar with mongodb but if you have the chats, can't you put the ids you need in a string or something and query for id and name for ids in the string?

Comment: You mean fetching each user per query. That exactly what I don't want to do. It will be way too much overhead. I need a way to make a single query and get a combined result. It doesn't even need to me JOIN simulation. I just want all the loading to happen in database. Something like (in text) "load content and before returning the result, load other objects." Or maybe doing an IN query. I don't know which one is possible or efficient.

Comment: I was referring to an IN construction. When you Google it you will find some workarounds, suggestions. It doesn't seem like it can be easily done.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1: Add the username to chat message documents. Like you said, if the username changes, you need to change the username on all the user's chats.

2: Do an application-level join. You don't need to do 20 queries to get the 20 names. You can first retrieve all the chats, then collect all of the `user_id` values and do one query. For example:

```
var results = [
    { "_id" : 0, "from" : 43, "to" : 86, "message" : "sup?" },
    { "_id" : 1, "from" : 99, "to" : 86, "message" : "yo" }
]
var from_users = db.users.find({ "_id" : { "$in" : results.map(function(doc) { return doc.from }) } }).toArray()
```

Now you can use the `from_users` to populate the username into `results` or create your desired document structure. Note that results from the `$in` are necessarily returned in the order of elements in the array argument to `$in` - this is commonly expected/desired but it's not the case.